# If a row matches a criteria do paste in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, paste

Let's imagine you have a dataframe with two columns `ID` and `POSITION`. I want to paste some text depending on the ID value.

I want to paste the ID value with `GK0000` (when ID>10) or `GK00000` (when ID<10) along with `.2:`, `POSITION` value, `..` and the following `POSITION` value *(POSITION+1)*

For example if `ID = 1` and `POSITION = 10`, the result would be **GK000001.2:10..11** and if `ID = 10` and `POSITION = 10`, the result would be **GK000010.2:10..11**

In Excel I can do this being `A` as `ID` and `B` as `POSITION` using `=IF(A2<10,CONCATENATE("GK00000",A2,".2:",B2,"..",B2+1),CONCATENATE("GK0000",A2,".2:",B2,"..",B2+1))` but I want to add it to my R script line.

I give you a short example of my input data just ilustrative

```
ID <- c(1,5,9,10,12)
POSITION <- c(10,50,90,100,120)
df <- cbind(ID,POSITION)
```

and the result I'm expecting is

```
CONCAT <- c("GK000001.2:10..11","GK000005.2:50..51","GK000009.2:90..91",
            "GK000010.2:100..101","GK000012.2:120..121")
dfResult <- cbind(ID,POSITION,CONCAT)
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. If `A2<10` paste a string with 5 zeros, then `A2` then `".2:"` then `B2..B2+1`. But `dfResult` has only 5 `CONCAT` values and both `A` and `B` jump from 1 to 5 to 9 to 10 to 12.

Comment: You're going to need to do better with your reprex, please. (1) Your `df` is a numeric matrix, and then in `dfResult` you column-bind strings to `df`, so the first two columns are no longer a number ... perhaps you should be using `data.frame`?; and (2) your strings have five values but your original matrix has 12 rows, there should be the same size. (Your code here produces a warning and naively recycles the strings, almost certainly not what you want/need.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question asks for a string format given two arguments, `A` and `B` and a number of digits.

```
concat <- function(A, B, digits = 6){
  fmt <- paste0("%0", digits, "d")
  fmt <- paste0("GK", fmt, ".2:%d..%d")
  sprintf(fmt, A, B, B + 1)
}

concat(df[, 'ID'], df[, 'POSITION'], 6)
# [1] "GK000001.2:10..11"   "GK000002.2:20..21"   "GK000003.2:30..31"  
# [4] "GK000004.2:40..41"   "GK000005.2:50..51"   "GK000006.2:60..61"  
# [7] "GK000007.2:70..71"   "GK000008.2:80..81"   "GK000009.2:90..91"  
#[10] "GK000010.2:100..101" "GK000011.2:110..111" "GK000012.2:120..121"
```